# How to create project by GCP deployment manager API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

I can follow the [tutorial](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/tree/master/examples/v2/project_creation) to create project by `gcloud deployment-manager` command and template files.

My question is how to use **deployment manager API** to do the same thing. I found the [insert method](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/reference/latest/deployments/insert) API in the document, but when I use this API to create project, I meet the error: `Error 404: Failed to find project test-site-301, notFound"`

How do I specify the project ID before the project has been created? Or I should use other API for project creation?

Thanks

---

Update. 2018.01.15

I think I found the answer. When creating a new project by deployment manager API, the project parameter should be the project which manages the deployment (i.e. host project) NOT the project which will be created.

Answer (score 0):

For project creation you should use Resource Manager API with [projects.create](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/create) method.

Review documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#creating_a_project) where different ways of creating project are described.

Comment: Hi komarkovich,   

my purpose is to use deployment manager (DM) to create the project, bcz in that way I can leverage `infrastructure as code` concept. 

In the deployment manager github example, I can use DM template to create a **shared vpc project** by one line command. If I use resource manager API, that will be serveral API calls I think.